# Building SQL Server Database Project In Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, msbuild, .net-core, sql-server-data-tools

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API application that is hosted in an Ubuntu environment. So far, I've had great success getting things building and running (for the .NET Core app) in Ubuntu.

For the database, I have a SqlProj included in my solution. The project includes typical things such as tables, SPs, and pre/post deployment scripts. I'm using the following command (on my Windows-based dev machine) to build and deploy this project:

```
msbuild .\MyProject.DB.sqlproj /t:Build /t:Publish /P:SqlPublishProfilePath="./PublishProfiles/MyProject.DB.publish.xml"
```

When I take this approach, everything builds and deploys properly; however, since I will be taking advantage of the .NET Core CLI commands + CI/CD that targets an Ubuntu environment, I'd like to do something more like:

```
dotnet msbuild .\MyProject.DB.sqlproj /t:Build /t:Publish /P:SqlPublishProfilePath="./PublishProfiles/MyProject.DB.publish.xml"
```

In Windows, I immediately get the error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Basically, what I'm asking is how to successfully build and deploy a SqlProj project in an Ubuntu environment. I've tried Googling, but I have had zero luck thus far. All of the similar issues that I've found were for individuals who were editing their .proj file to target their VS folder's SSDT. All of these individuals were fixing the issue in Windows. This approach will not work in Ubuntu, since the targets file uses Windows registry keys.

EDIT: I'm aware that SSDT is needed in order to perform such a deployment using MSBuild. I've found no evidence that installing/using SSDT is even possible in Ubuntu. If it is not, perhaps there is an alternative solution?

FYI, I'm aware that using a code-first approach with EF Core is possible. I'm attempting to take the raw SP approach (along with leveraging indexes) and keep track of all of my code using SqlProj instead. This will all be stored and CI/CDed from a Git repo.

Comment: How are you able to compile the sqlproj on Ubuntu?  I cannot get past msbuild errors.

Comment: @harsimranb, I am not able to get this to build in Ubuntu. Unfortunately, this is the problem. MSBuild does not work at this time for .SqlProj. I still haven't found a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## My 2020 Solution

I would like to revisit this in 2020 with an updated answer to my original question.

I have taken a different approach to building an deploying SQL Server projects. My current approach is to build a pipeline that uses a vs2017-win2016 agent and use this to build a .dacpac. From there, you build a deployment pipeline to deploy the dacpac (from your artifact drop) out to the SQL Server instance.

This approach better accommodates DevOps methodologies and removes the manual process associated with my previous solution.

You can read more about this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-dacpac?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. May I suggest you accept your own answer (it is how you solved the problem after all) to make it more visible to future visitors?

Comment: @brandon-avant But this does only work on Azure DevOps or Azure DevOps Server, right? I assume if one wants to build and deploy the project on Linux (or a Linux-based container) the SDK-solution would work better, isn´t it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this NuGet package to deploy without installing SSDT https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild
I don't know if it will run on Ubuntu or integrate at all with the dotnet cli

Comment: So this definitely seems like a path worth following. I've begun researching the implications of taking this route and I'm pretty stuck at the moment. I first tried adding this package to my SqlProj but I'm greeted by the error from before plus "Unable to create dependency graph file for project 'Myproject.sqlproj". Cannot add package reference. I also can't find any evidence (or guidance) of being able to implement this from the CLI or from a Linux environment. Is it possible that no one has tried this yet? I guess I understand, since a lot of this new; so it's possible...

Comment: Right, unfortunately you can't add it as a reference to a SQL project. You can create a separate "build" project and invoke SQLPackage through PowerShell or the commandline. Not sure if it is compatible with bash or .net core though.

Comment: I will try that out. The one concern I do have is that it seems like calling msbuild from the command line will just revert to what was installed prior to my installing this package (i.e. the VS MSBuild installation). How can I explicitly call the assemblies installed by the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild package? I want to make sure I understand this part prior to attempting this in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not totally sure, since I'm doing it on Windows and using the package to ensure deployment of a built DacPac is using the correct/same version of SQLpackage no matter what version is installed or not on the agent. I may be wrong though, we might have updated the sqlproj to point to the .target file inside the packages folder

Comment: Ok. Well I appreciate the help thus far. I will began researching this path until a better solution comes along. I will post my results once I've either hit a wall or found a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Azure Data Studio now has an extension that lets you build database projects (sqlproj) using the dotnet tool.  The brains behind building the project lies in the SQL Server Tools package, which is where the extension gets the required "BuildDirectory" DLL and targets dependencies.

Though not documented, if you want to set this up completely headless outside of Azure Data Studio, you can follow their CLI guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-database-project-extension-build-from-command-line?view=sql-server-ver15, but instead extract the necessary files from the RHEL release in https://github.com/microsoft/sqltoolsservice/releases and then follow the rest of the extension's documentation.  Here is a working Dockerfile that demonstrates the approach:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl

# SSDT dlls and targets file used by Azure Data Studio Extension can be found in the SQL Tools Service project
RUN curl -sSL -o /tmp/sqltools.tar.gz https://github.com/microsoft/sqltoolsservice/releases/download/v3.0.0-release.181/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer-rhel-x64-net6.0.tar.gz

# Extract files that are required per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-database-project-extension-build-from-command-line?view=sql-server-ver15

RUN mkdir /tmp/sqltools && tar -xzf /tmp/sqltools.tar.gz -C /tmp/sqltools && \
  mkdir /app/BuildDirectory && cd /tmp/sqltools && cp \
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll \
    Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll \
    Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets \
    Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll \
    Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll \
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll \
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll \
    Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll \
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll \
    System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll \
    System.IO.Packaging.dll \
  /app/BuildDirectory && \
  rm -r /tmp/sqltools

#dotnet build your-database-project.sqlproj /p:NetCoreBuild=true /p:NETCoreTargetsPath="/app/BuildDirectory"
```

The commented command at the end shows what you could run inside the container in the directory with your database project.

This can also then be combined with a container utilizing sqlpackage to implement a full dacpac build and publish automation toolset.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, it is possible to achieve this with dotnet cli and sqlpackage as explained [here](https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj) using an MSBuild Sdk.

You basically have a database project. Let's call it "DatabaseProject".

You create a new project which is a .NET standard c# library that you can call "DatabaseProject.Build".

Then you can configure you DatabaseProject.Build.csproj as such:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.11.4">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
       <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="..\DatabaseProject\**\*.sql" />
       <Content Remove="..\DatabaseProject\bin\*.sql" />
       <Content Remove="..\DatabaseProject\**\*.PostDeployment.sql" />
       <PostDeploy Include="..\DatabaseProject\**\*.PostDeployment.sql" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Be Aware** The version used **V1.11.4** is the one that supports the current .NET SDK shipped with visual studio at the time of the edit of this post. Check out [the github repo](https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj) to get the latest nuget version for your projet.

Using dotnet build will generate a dacpac that you will be able to use with either dotnet publish or [sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can then publish to you SqlServer instance.
If you're like me using a linux runner in your CI, you'll probably need SqlServer authentification method and then run either

```
sqlpackage /Action:Publish \    
/SourceFile:\"DatabaseProject.Build/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/DatabaseProject.Build.dacpac\" \
/TargetServerName:MyDatabaseServerName \
/TargetDatabaseName:MyDatabaseName \
/TargetUser:Username\
/TargetPassword:Password
```

or using a profile generated by visual studio :

```
sqlpackage /Action:Publish /Profile:\"DatabaseProject/PublishProfile/MyProfile.publish.xml\" /SourceFile:\"DatabaseProject.Build/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/DatabaseProject.Build.dacpac\"
```

or

```
dotnet publish /p:TargetServerName=MyServerName /p:TargetDatabaseName=MyDatabseName /p:TargetUser=<username> /p:TargetPassword=<password>
```

Comment: Nice, this was what I was originally looking for. I’ll need to give this a try at some point.

Comment: I've tested the first part (building) and it works perfectly. What I've done is to create a .csproj file in the same folder as my .sqlproj file. Any .sql files in the folder or subfolders will be included in the package, so make sure you exclude any scripts that should not be part of the DACPAC.

Comment: This solution uses donet 2.0 which already reached end of life (3.x also). Do you know any other solution for linux or I should better forget it and use a windows based system.

Comment: @PlayingWithBI I'm not sure what you mean by that sir, are you refering to the .net standard ? if that's the case, it should work on the current latest version of dotnet. You can check that out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). Although I haven't experimented on a fresh .net 5 project yet, the netstandard2.0 shouldn't be a problem. I would like to hear from you on that one if you actually give it a try =)

Comment: I managed to get it work using the MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj SDK, then I added a complex database project with security and view that uses the master database and I am not able to build it.

Comment: @PlayingWithBI well, my guess is you used the version of the Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.3.0" that i provided at the time. It indeed does not support .net 5 and you have an issue with the build. If you go to the github repo of the projet, you'll see that the version of the nuget package is now V1.11.4 and it supports .Net 5. So instead of 1.3.0 try with 1.11.4. I hope it solves you problem with the build. I'll also update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to whether or not this will work on Ubuntu, but we recently got through this on a Windows build machine that does not have SSDT installed, using the NuGet package mentioned above.  The breakthrough came from piecing together the details in the article below, specifically that using the SDK with MSBuild needed to have environment variables set in order to work.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/08/22/part-5-use-your-own-build-and-deployment-agent/

With that added info, we installed the NuGet package in the root of the solution folder and then wrote a build script in PowerShell. The script sets the environment variables first and then calls MSBuild on the SqlProj file with the appropriate output directory.  We don't specifically publish at that point, but instead publish the artifact to Octopus Deploy in our workflow which does the actual deployment.

Again, not sure it will help on Ubuntu, but thought the additional detail might be useful.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. What we will probably do for now is setup a Windows Server VM in our AWS setup and have it act as our build agent. I admit, I have more research to do in order to finalize this plan. Your information, along with the previous posters, should prove highly beneficial. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the easiest way to build DacPac file on a linux agent is done via [MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj](https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj)
Go to your database project directory in parallel to .sqlproj file create a directory like `DB.Build` under it create `DB.Build.csproj` copy.pase the content as below

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.1.0"> <!-- This will pull in the required tools and dependencies to build a .dacpac with .NET Core -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\src\DB\masterdata\**\*.sql" /> <!-- link in the new .csproj to the .sql scripts in your existing database project -->
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After run you will see dacpac file appears under `DB.Build/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/DB.Build.dacpac`

Here's my build agent output (Ubuntu agent on Azure devops)

```sh
Starting: SQL DB build Release
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.187.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.187.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.187.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" --configuration Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=/home/vsts/work/1/recommender-service-cicd/DacPac/
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 51.72 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.csproj.
  Using package name RecommenderAPI.DB.Build and version 1.0.0
  Using SQL Server version Sql150
  Deleting existing file /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/obj/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac
  Writing model to /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/obj/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac
  RecommenderAPI.DB.Build -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.71

Finishing: SQL DB build Release
```

> Note: Make sure to restore you NuGet packages in step prior to build

Answer (score 1):

The package often suggested by others, [R&R WFM's MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj](https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj) does not come from Microsoft, and it doesn't really do a "real SSDT build". It does not use SSDT build tools, it is a separate 3rd party tool that can generate limited DACPAC packages with reduced features. This info does not come from my experience with that tool. I read it somewhere when I tried to research what options I have left as I'm stuck with DACPACs and Linux. While I can't confirm that info in any way, it looks true, repo doesn't have 'Microsoft' logos anywhere, and I read such warnings on multiple unrelated sites, posted by supposedly different people.

That being said, it's an awesome tool that certainly required huge amount of workand knowledge.

***But there's another one as well.***

Recently Microsoft started developing [their own cross-platform SSDT build tool, Microsoft.Build.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Sql#versions-body-tab) coming from [DacFx](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx). At the time of writing this, it's still in `preview` and the current version is `0.1.10`. You'll often see `0.1.3` or `0.1.7` if you search for articles about how to use that.

Microsoft provided a [nice guide](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Build.Sql/docs/Converting-Existing.md) how to convert an existing `.sqlproj` generated by VisualStudio+SSDT. It's concise, a bit too concise, and requires minor obvious fixes. The article also points to a minimalistic new-style .sqlproj file, the link is broken, but the [file resides in a nearby folder](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/blob/main/samples/SdkStyleDatabaseProject/sample.sqlproj).

The article mentions that new-style projects support globbing (so Include="folder/**/*.sql" instead of listing all files), and that including all SQL files is already the default behavior, so an 'empty' project file like the sample one will grab all SQL files - but be careful, and read the final paragraph about compatibility with VisualStudio.

Using this info, I was able to convert my .sqlproj file. I did the steps explained there, and also I didn't remove any now-not-needed file inclusions, so VS is happy.

My .sqlproj file looks now like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <!-- IMPORTANT: this is a PREVIEW tooling, keep an eye on changes and notes -->
  <!-- https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Build.Sql/docs/Converting-Existing.md -->
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.Sql" Version="0.1.10-preview" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Name>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    <ModelCollation>1033,CI</ModelCollation>
    <TargetDatabaseSet>True</TargetDatabaseSet>
    <DefaultCollation>Latin1_General_100_CI_AS</DefaultCollation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
    <Folder Include="Tables" />
    <Folder Include="Views" />
    <Folder Include="Procedures" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Tables\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
    <Build Include="Tables\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
    <Build Include="Views\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
    <Build Include="Views\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
    <Build Include="Procedures\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
    <Build Include="Procedures\xxxxxxxxx.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <RefactorLog Include="xxxxxxxxx.refactorlog" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PostDeploy Include="Script.PostDeployment1.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PreDeploy Include="Script.PreDeployment1.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="xxxxxxxxx.publish.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

That 'xxx' parts is just anonymization of course.

I was able to successfully build this project and get a DACPAC file by simple

```
cd solutionroot
dotnet build MyProject.sln
```

or

```
cd solutionroot/dbproject
dotnet build MyProject.sqlproj
```

I did not have to add `/p:NetCoreBuild=true` - the tooling in `0.1.10` detects that it is ran from `dotnet` command and sets this automatically.

This worked both when the build was done at my local dev machine (Win10, VS2022, `dotnet --version` = 7.0.302), and when ran on CI agent (Amazon Linux 2).

The CI system was AWS CodeBuild and script used was:

```
version: 0.2    
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: latest

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - dotnet --version
      - dotnet restore

  build:
    commands:
      - dotnet build -c Release
```

Not much happening really. The relevant output parts were:

```
[Container] 2023/07/08 20:36:06 Running command dotnet --version
6.0.408
(...snip...)
  xxxx.Database -> /codebuild/output/src3703237027/src/git-codecommit.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/bin/Release/xxxx.dll
  xxxx.Database -> /codebuild/output/src3703237027/src/git-codecommit.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/bin/Release/xxxx.dacpac
```

So it actually took 6.0, different than on my local. A bit odd, but it still built the dacpac.

Two things worth noting - while `dotnet build` is able to build a DACPAC, the tooling is "preview" and if I remember correcly, the docs at GitHub mention that not all features are supported. I have no idea how the feature gaps compare to the gaps in rr-wfm's nuget, but the tool is still developed, so there's hope :)

The second thing to note is that while `dotnet build` is able to build the DACPAC, the `dotnet publish` is NOT able to run it. Trying to

```
dotnet publish -c Release -p:SqlPublishProfilePath=./xxxx.publish.xml
```

at best currently ends up with following error

```
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.sql/0.1.10-preview/tools/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1869,7): error MSB4018: The "SqlPublishTask" task failed unexpectedly.
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.sql/0.1.10-preview/tools/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1869,7): error MSB4018: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.sql/0.1.10-preview/tools/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1869,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.sql/0.1.10-preview/tools/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1869,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..ctor(String connectionString)
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.build.sql/0.1.10-preview/tools/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1869,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.CachedRegistryConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean loadFromRegistry)
```

I get this error BOTH when I try to run the `dotnet publish` on my local dev machine (where everything worked), and obviously also when I try that at the CI agent.

This is because the `dotnet publish` command isn't currently supported by the `0.1.10` tooling. It probably will not be supported at all, for some probably important, probably internal reason.

Instead of `dotnet publish`, a [separate tool is provided by DacFx, called SqlPackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlPackage). It's advertised as [the cross-platform tool for running DACPACs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver16#installation-cross-platform).

It can be installed with `dotnet`:

```
dotnet tool install -g microsoft.sqlpackage
```

and it can `publish` the DACPAC, although with a bit different commandline syntax (see the previous link above for details):

```
SqlPackage /Action:Publish /SourceFile:".dacpac" /Profile:"....."
```

I have not tried installing and running this SqlPackage tool, but looks very promising.